# Reactjs avoid passing parameters through nesting

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using `reactjs` with `redux` and I am a newbie.

In my current code I have an object which gets passed through to the under lying code. I want to avoid this and have it in the props so I do not need to nest it. Is this achievable using reactjs?

Example:

```
module.exports ({ obj1 }) return <ul text: obj1></ul>
```

This goes further down into other method calls.

Should I expand the object props and avoid passing the full object down?

Comment: It sounds like you want your component to be a `connect`ed component so that your state can be passed down to the component as props. Is this what  you're after? If so you can wrap your export with `connect` and add the data to props in `mapStateToProps`.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely think you should expand the object and only pass down the props required by your child components.  This way you allow for the development of components with minimal responsibility, which promotes reuse.  It's a common pattern to create Container and Presentational components.

Dan Abramov, the creator of Redux, has some amazing egghead tutorials which will help you for sure.  Check them out here:

- https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

And when you have built up some experience, check out his newer set of lessons which deal with some more advanced concepts (stick with the first lessons though until you have a proper grasp of Redux).

- https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

Comment: Depends on your use-case really.  How many props are contained within `obj1`?  Do your sub-components really need all the properties?  Keeping your components focused on props that they will actually consume/use will promote component re-use.  Def check out those courses. :)

Comment: The object is really big. The sub components require all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

The [context API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) was purposefully designed for passing data through the component tree, while still retaining existing behavior related to properties.